# What does "sad" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am reading a computer article about virtual machines.

My question is that what "sad" means in the sentence below?

I don't think it means "unhappy", because the writer says that he loves virtual machines.

> I love virtual machines (VMs) and I have done for a long time. If that
>   makes me “sad” or an “anorak”, so be it. I love them because they are
>   so much fun, as well as being so useful.

Comment: I think he means it in the sense of *pathetic* or *lame*. The term *anorak* means (in BrE, not AmE) a geek obsessed with a specific subject (I think the Japanese call this kind of person *otaku*?). So he might be saying if he's performed as being pathetic for being so obsessed with VMs, well then so be it: he doesn't care, he loves them nevertheless.

Comment: @Dan Bron: I'm guessing that would be your less-that-perfect predictive text that came up with ***performed*** instead of ***perceived***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You guessed correctly. I'm looking for a new text-predictor, would you mind submitting an application?

Comment: @Dan: My comment *was* my application! (For a small monthly fee, you can email all your comments to me for proofreading prior to posting! :)

Comment: "Sad" can be used to mean "pitiful" even when applied directly. Often when one labels someone else as "sad" in American English, they don't mean that the other is actually feeling sadness, but that they are a pitiful or pathetic person; the speaker would supposedly feel sadness upon seeing the person, but often this isn't actually the case.

Comment: Between "sad" and "anorak", "sad" is not the one I would have needed help with.

Answer (score 4):

He means to say he doesn't care, even if he seems pathetic or geeky or introvert, He still love VMs anyways.

Comment: Yes. *Sad* and *anorak* are in quotation marks: they represent how **other** people characterize the author's obsessions.

Comment: @StoneyB , i want to translate the sentence into my native language. can i say something like this? if people feel pity about me, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Waheed Khan , would u answer the question i asked StoneyB? he is apparently not online. Do u know the answer?

Comment: @amin It's not so much *pity* as *scorn*, I think

Comment: StoneyB, sorry man I was also not available, yeah the sense is right but the sentence should be `If people feel pity for me, It doesn't matter!` I think so, I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance "sad" is a synonym for "pitiable" or "pathetic".

Comment: While your answer is somewhat correct,  it would be better if it elaborated on the nuance of using sad instead of pathetic or some other synonym.  There's also a sense of unfashionable to sad in this context. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sad